# Is there a performance testing tool for dll's? (not for source code)

Tags: asp.net, performance, profiling

I know red-gate's ANTS Performance Profiler but it works with source code. I have an ASP.NET web application that is deployed on a remote server. I'm going to test its performance while it is working on the server.

My main goal is to detect what method of what class is slow and then is a bottleneck. Is there a way or a tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your best option is to implement [Health Monitoring in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998306.aspx).

> ASP.NET health monitoring enables you
>   to do the following tasks:
>
> - Monitor the performance of an application to make sure that it is
>     healthy.
> - Rapidly diagnose applications or systems that are failing.
> - Appraise significant events during the life cycle of an application.
> - Monitor live ASP.NET applications, individually or across a Web farm.
> - Log events that do not necessarily relate to errors in an ASP.NET
>     application.

Ref.: [ASP.NET Health Monitoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx)

Also [Health Monitoring in ASP.NET 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102851/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031407-1.aspx)

Comment: Is there any open source and none MS equivalent for it?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ASP.NET. I want to know just for better knowledge.